# Can kangaroos walk backwards?

Tags: biology, zoology, australia

[image: kangaroo]<sub>[Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/shebalso/1928593646)</sub>

From [Exploring Nature](http://www.exploringnature.org/db/detail.php?dbID=17&detID=136):

> They cannot jump backward because of
>   their thick, muscular tail. **Their long
>   feet and heavy tail also make walking
>   impossible, forward or backward**.

The [Australian 'Coat of Arms'](http://www.itsanhonour.gov.au/coat-arms/index.cfm) features an **Emu** and a **Kangaroo**:

[image: Coat of Arms] <sub>[Source](http://www.itsanhonour.gov.au/coat-arms/index.cfm)</sub>

> Some say the kangaroo and emu were
>   chosen to symbolise a nation moving
>   forward. This is based on the **common
>   belief that neither animal can move
>   backwards easily**.

My question:

**Can kangaroos walk backwards?**

Is walking backwards just difficult for them or is it anatomically impossible?

Comment: As well as being skeptical that they can move backwards, I'm skeptical as to whether that was the reason they were chosen.

Comment: @Andrew - Since it's only 100 years old I also find it strange that it's not __known__.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Kangaroos cannot move backwards easily.  But they do it [while fighting](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEDq0SAYW44) (YouTube, 0:35 is particularly clear where one is jumping backwards away from another).

Comment: +1 for visual evidence. It looks like kangaroos depend on their tail when walking backwards. They basically use it like a "third leg".